# Фильтр списка (оставить только числовые значения)

Tags: python, list

Нужно отфильтровать список по такому признаку:
элемент списка имеет только цифры в своём составе

пример списка:

```
ids = ['246817', '246815', '246796', 'yandex_rtb_R-A-332375-1', '246795']
```

То есть нужно оставить только числовые значения и убрать `yandex_rtb_R-A-332375-1`.

Answer (score 3):

```
numbers = [n for n in ids if n.isdigit()]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

ids = ['246817', '246815', '246796', 'yandex_rtb_R-A-332375-1', '246795']
list(filter(lambda x: re.search('^\d+$', x), ids))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну тут `filter` прямо напрашивается (хотя это и эквивалентно решению Эникейщик-а):

```
ids = ['246817', '246815', '246796', 'yandex_rtb_R-A-332375-1', '246795']
print(list(filter(str.isdigit, ids)))
```

Вывод:

```
['246817', '246815', '246796', '246795']
```